# How do I code the sum of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

Any time I try to compile it the output is 0. Not sure why but please anyone help.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[ ] = {1,2,3};
    int array2[ ] = {10,9,8};
    int[] c = new int[array1.length];


    for(int i = 0; i<array1.length ; i++){

      c[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];

      System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this `ans` variable you are printing?

Comment: `ans` is undefined, but it's also never updated

Answer (score 1):

Here are the wrong:

- `ans` is never defined.
- you sum to `c` array but never print them.

Here is what you should do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[ ] = {1,2,3};
    int array2[ ] = {10,9,8};
    int[] c = new int[array1.length];

    int sumOfAll = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<array1.length ; i++){
    c[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
        sumOfAll += c[i];
        // if you just want the sum of each index.
        System.out.println("Sum each: " + c[i]);
    }
    // if you want to sum the total of array in c
    System.out.println("Sum of all: " + sumOfAll);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate array elements into separate loops, summing each number to a variable, and then printing it, like this:

```
public class SumArray {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            int array1[ ] = {1,2,3};
            int array2[ ] = {10,10,10,10};

            int sum = 0;

            for (int i : array2) {
                sum += i;
            }

            for (int i : array1) {
                sum += i;
            }

            System.out.println("result: " + sum);
        }

}
```

Output:

```
result: 46
```

Or with for with temporary variable:

```
public class SumArray {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            int array1[ ] = {1,2,3};
            int array2[ ] = {10,10,10,10};

            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                sum += array2[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                sum += array1[i];
            }

            System.out.println("result: " + sum);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int array1[ ] = {1,2,3};
    int array2[ ] = {10,9,8};
    int[] c = new int[array1.length];


    for(int i = 0; i<array1.length ; i++){

      c[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];

      System.out.println(c[i]);
    }
   }
```